# Changing BarChartActivity to StackedBarActivity

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am trying to change my BarChart implementation to StackedBar, but i can't to find the way because between BarCart and StackedBar there are the same code. I can't to find the difference. Both Charts use `com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart` So when i run my App with StackedBar the result is a BarChart

this is my code:

```
private void initBarchart(ArrayList<String> days, ArrayList<UserModels.MainStackedDataObject> mainStackedData) {
            mBarChart.setDescription("");
            mBarChart.setNoDataText(getString(R.string.without_content));
            mBarChart.findViewWithTag(false);
            mBarChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
            mBarChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
            mBarChart.setScaleXEnabled(false);
            mBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
            mBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
            Legend l = mBarChart.getLegend();
            l.setEnabled(false);

            YAxis y_Axis = mBarChart.getAxisLeft();

            y_Axis.setValueFormatter(null);
            y_Axis.setDrawGridLines(true);
            y_Axis.setSpaceTop(10f);
            XAxis x_Axis = mBarChart.getXAxis();
            x_Axis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
            x_Axis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            mBarChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
            setDataBarChart(days, mainStackedData);

        }
```

I don't know that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in how you **create an entry**:

Normal bar:
`BarEntry(float value, int xIndex)`

Stacked bar:
`BarEntry(float[] stackvalues, int xIndex)`